# Export to excel using EPlus showing datetime as UTC time in the export sheet

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

When I am trying to export data to excel using EPPlus all DateTime values are displaying as UTC time instead of the datetime value in the output. For example: if the value is `13/11/2019 05:35:34 PM`. In the exported excel sheet it is displaying as `13/11/2019 01:35:34 PM`.

How come the values are automatically getting converted? Please help.

Also, I have set the format for datetime values like below:

```
worksheet.Column(col).Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM";
```

Is this an issue?

Comment: Are you sure the value isn't getting overwritten anywhere? 05 (AM or PM) does not convert to 01 (AM or PM) it would have to be 13 or 17.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have checked the output value in client side  and it was showing 13/11/2019 17:35:34. But once exported, the value comes like 13/11/2019 01:35:34 PM. Whether excel automatically converting it to UTC time. I am not sure about it.

Comment: What Epplus eventually does is use `DateTime.ToOADate()` to get it in a number that excel will like: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/v4.5.3/EPPlus/ExcelWorksheet.cs#L3888   That is strange that it is being converted.  What is the `DatetTime.Kind` of your dt objects?  Could there be something that excel is doing based on local settings?  Maybe post more code.